# Restsharp JSON Body Needing Brackets

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

The API I am interacting with is refusing to accept the body formatted this way:

```
{"op": "replace","path": "/PCF_AVALARAT","value": "DM040100"}
```

It is requiring it to be wrapped with brackets like this:

```
[{"op": "replace","path": "/PCF_AVALARAT","value": "DM040100"}], I can't get my C# Restsharp code to add those wrapping brackets to the bo for the life of medy.
```

Current version of my code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("op", "add");
values.Add("path", "/PCF_AVALARAT");
values.Add("value", ATC);

request2.AddJsonBody(values);
```

Comment: Create a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` and add your dictionary in as it's first member.  Use the dictionary as the body

Comment: The brackets represent an array. The API accepts an array of objects.

Comment: @Flydog57 you did it!  I've been struggling with this for a whole day.  Thankful for people smarter than I.

Comment: @BrentAllison: The square brackets signify a collection.  The curly brackets signify an *object*.  The thing is, a JSON object is just a list of property names and property values.  A `Dictionary<string, object>` is a perfectly adequate representation of a JSON object.  If all the properties are string-valued, then a `Dictionary<string, string>` fills the bill.  So, if you have `[{"op": "replace","path": "/PCF_AVALARAT","value": "DM040100"}]`, the inner part represents an object with only string-valued properties, the outer part a collection.  So a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` just works